# How to install Touchégg on Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, software-installation, touchpad

How do I install [Touchégg](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/) on Fedora 20?

https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode seems to be written for Ubuntu (Debian) systems, which makes me confused;

> 1 - Download and unzip the source code:

No problems. Just do what it says.

> 2 - Install Touchégg dependencies. In Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot and recent open a terminal and type:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get build-dep touchegg`

How do I do this in Fedora? Or, if necessary, how do I do the alternative version "`sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev utouch libgeis-dev libx11-6 libxtst-dev`" in Fedora?

> 3 - Compile and install Touchégg:
> $ qmake
> $ make
> $ sudo make install

I didn't get this far, but can I do exactly as it says? Do `qmake`, `make` and `make install` exist in Fedora and work as in Ubuntu/Debian?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How does https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode not provide enough information?

Comment: The guide seems to be for Ubuntu (Debian), and I don't know how to `apt-get build-dep touchegg` in Fedora, what additional packages I need or even how to compile and install (I'm very new to Fedora).

Comment: You should do a source build (using v.1.1.1 currently at the top of [this list](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/downloads/list)); there's a link inside the README to [here](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode).  If you have problems with that, you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: If you don't know how to build programs from source, better stay well away from this until you know a lot more about your system. "Just install <foo> (from source)" is very rarely the best option.

Comment: Great idea! Let's stay away from this until I magically know how to do it! :)

Comment: @lindhe - do you still want a answer?

Comment: Yes, that would be nice.

Comment: 64bit and/or 32bit? (I pretty much have a solution using old package for Fedora 21 64bit). And do you wan the package for the GUI?

Comment: I'm running 64-bit. I don't need a GUI, but it might be nice to include that for others.

Comment: Just letting you guys know that it'll probably be quite a while before I'm looking into this again. I've been on Arch for a while, and everything works nice so I don't think I'll get back to Fedora any time soon. As a consequence I can't try possible answers, thus not marking them as "Correct answer" either. I let this one be open for the moment, someone might get an answer that helps them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mhoeher/multitouch/
It gives a repository that you can pull from using dnf and includes all the dependancies needed.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think you will have too much luck doing this, but lets give a shot.**

If you read [the installation wiki](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/wiki/How-to-compile-Touch%C3%A9gg-source-code), you will notice this:

> If your are using a previous Ubuntu version or **other distro these are the required packages:**
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev utouch libgeis-dev libx11-6 libxtst-dev
> ```

So, you only need to find the equivalent package of each one:

- `utouch-evemu-devel` is the equivalent to `utouch` in Fedora 19 and earlier versions, then they renamed it to `geis`, further complicating the problem. Search for `geis-devel` or `utoch-evemu-devel` packages. This should also solve the `libgeis-dev` package
- `build-essential` [is the easier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1344/41104), just run `yum groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"`.
- `libqt4-dev` is `libqt4-devel`. RPM (RHEL and derivatives) uses `-devel` for development packages, contrasting APT's (Debian and derivatives) `-dev`.
- [`libx11-6` is just `libX11`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1163/41104). If some problem arises, try the `-devel` package instead.
- `libXtst-devel` is the equivalent to `libxtst-dev`.

This should account for all necessary packages. Once you have installed all of them, just run the good old `qmake && make` to make sure the packages build correctly. After that I recommend you to [build an RPM package](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package), so you can install and uninstall easily.

Comment: Hm. I seem to have trouble installing the utouch equivalent. I found nothing good with `yum search geis`, `... utouch` or `... utouch` and `qmake && make` just gives `./src/touchegg/util/Include.h:36:27: fatal error: geis/geis.h: No such file or directory`. Because I guess I should use qmake (installed qt-devel to get qmake-qt4) since there is no file "configure"?? `./configure` just outputs `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @lindhe you need to install geis-devel, no geis.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be extremely tricky in Fedora.  I am trying in F23 on a Fujitsu Lifebook T935, which has a Wacom touchscreen.

I was able to download and compile various source packages from Ubuntu Lauchpad using Bazaar, which have the following dependency structure:

touchegg > geis > grail > frame

I also had to install a number of Fedora packages for other dependencies, but there is no current Fedora equivalent for these.  Frame and Grail seemed to compile OK, but when I run make on geis I get exactly the same problem(s) as here (https://forums.archlinux.fr/viewtopic.php?t=14127) depending on whether or not I have a copy of `frame_x11.h` in `/usr/local/include/oif` - or equivalently symlink from `/usr/local/src/geis/include` to `/usr/local/src/frame/include/oif`